# Re-flag after retracting flag

Tags: support, flags

**TL;DR:**

How can I re-flag something after I've flagged it once and then retracted (unflagged) it?

**A BIT MORE:**

I flagged as a duplicate then incorrectly realized it was not a duplicate so I retracted, then I realized *it was* a duplicate after all but now cannot seem to re-flag. Duplication of question remains a problem. What can I do?

Comment: You can leave a comment under the question or if you don't mind to chat you can post a so called cv-pls in the SOCVR chat room but do read our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) first, specially https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-cv-pls-not-a-habit

Comment: you can try to edit the question, at least wuth up and down vote ot works

Comment: In those situations the best thing you can do is leave a comment saying something like "likely a duplicate of X". Then future visitors can see it and flag/vote with that target. Yes, you won't be able to but overall the situations where you flag with one reason then have to change to another should be rare.